# Windows 10 slide show shorter than 1 minute

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

In Windows 10 you can create Desktop background slide shows. The minimum time between two images is one minute.

How can I make the interval shorter?

Comment: based on win7 Take a look in the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow , for the item "Interval" looks like it is in miliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the keyboard command Win + R to launch the Run window
2. Copy & paste this into the Run window: `control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper` and then hit OK. It's a direct route to the old Control Panel setting for slideshow control.
3. You should notice new timing options near the bottom, including 10 and 30-second intervals along with more options for various hours. Just pick the one you want and hit Save changes.
4. Near the bottom, you should also notice the Shuffle option is now listed here as well. Simply check the box and hit Save changes when finished.

If you want something other than the default options you can follow @Psycogeek's suggestion, you just need to reboot the computer after making the change (I tested his suggestion first and it worked for me).

Comment: The command no longer works in Windows 10 Creators Update. Use this command instead: 
`shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper`

Comment: Ignatius' suggestion works fine, even on Windows 7. But... is there a way to make a shortcut for this command?

Answer (score 6):

Since *Creators Update* that you cannot use the previous command anymore:

```
control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper
```

The alternative is to run:

```
shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper
```

...which should be preceeded by `explorer.exe` if you intend to call it from another process or a shortcut, like so:

```
explorer.exe shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper
```

Additionally, in case you are interested, here are a few other potentially useful shell UIDs:

```
Add Network Location                            shell:::{D4480A50-BA28-11d1-8E75-00C04FA31A86}
Administrative Tools                            shell:::{D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153}
Applications                                    shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}
AutoPlay                                        shell:::{9C60DE1E-E5FC-40f4-A487-460851A8D915}
BitLocker Drive Encryption                      shell:::{D9EF8727-CAC2-4e60-809E-86F80A666C91}
Bluetooth Devices                               shell:::{28803F59-3A75-4058-995F-4EE5503B023C}
Color Management                                shell:::{B2C761C6-29BC-4f19-9251-E6195265BAF1}
Command Folder                                  shell:::{437ff9c0-a07f-4fa0-af80-84b6c6440a16}
Common Places FS Folder                         shell:::{d34a6ca6-62c2-4c34-8a7c-14709c1ad938}
Control Panel                                   shell:::{5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0}
Control Panel (All Tasks)                       shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
Control Panel (always Category view)            shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}
Control Panel (always Icons view)               shell:::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}
Credential Manager                              shell:::{1206F5F1-0569-412C-8FEC-3204630DFB70}
Date and Time                                   shell:::{E2E7934B-DCE5-43C4-9576-7FE4F75E7480}
Default Programs                                shell:::{17cd9488-1228-4b2f-88ce-4298e93e0966}
delegate folder that appears in Computer        shell:::{b155bdf8-02f0-451e-9a26-ae317cfd7779}
Desktop (folder)                                shell:::{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
Device Manager                                  shell:::{74246bfc-4c96-11d0-abef-0020af6b0b7a}
Devices and Printers                            shell:::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}
Display                                         shell:::{C555438B-3C23-4769-A71F-B6D3D9B6053A}
Documents (folder)                              shell:::{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}
Downloads (folder)                              shell:::{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
Ease of Access Center                           shell:::{D555645E-D4F8-4c29-A827-D93C859C4F2A}
E-mail (default e-mail program)                 shell:::{2559a1f5-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
Family Safety                                   shell:::{96AE8D84-A250-4520-95A5-A47A7E3C548B}
Favorites                                       shell:::{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}
File Explorer Options                           shell:::{6DFD7C5C-2451-11d3-A299-00C04F8EF6AF}
File History                                    shell:::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}
Font Settings                                   shell:::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}
Fonts (folder)                                  shell:::{BD84B380-8CA2-1069-AB1D-08000948F534}
Frequent folders                                shell:::{3936E9E4-D92C-4EEE-A85A-BC16D5EA0819}
Games Explorer                                  shell:::{ED228FDF-9EA8-4870-83b1-96b02CFE0D52}
Get Programs                                    shell:::{15eae92e-f17a-4431-9f28-805e482dafd4}
Help and Support                                shell:::{2559a1f1-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
HomeGroup (settings)                            shell:::{67CA7650-96E6-4FDD-BB43-A8E774F73A57}
HomeGroup (users)                               shell:::{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}
Hyper-V Remote File Browsing                    shell:::{0907616E-F5E6-48D8-9D61-A91C3D28106D}
Indexing Options                                shell:::{87D66A43-7B11-4A28-9811-C86EE395ACF7}
Infared (if installed)                          shell:::{A0275511-0E86-4ECA-97C2-ECD8F1221D08}
Installed Updates                               shell:::{d450a8a1-9568-45c7-9c0e-b4f9fb4537bd}
Internet Options (Internet Explorer)            shell:::{A3DD4F92-658A-410F-84FD-6FBBBEF2FFFE}
Keyboard Properties                             shell:::{725BE8F7-668E-4C7B-8F90-46BDB0936430}
Language settings                               shell:::{BF782CC9-5A52-4A17-806C-2A894FFEEAC5}
Libraries                                       shell:::{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}
Location Information (Phone and Modem)          shell:::{40419485-C444-4567-851A-2DD7BFA1684D}
Location Settings                               shell:::{E9950154-C418-419e-A90A-20C5287AE24B}
Media Servers                                   shell:::{289AF617-1CC3-42A6-926C-E6A863F0E3BA}
Mouse Properties                                shell:::{6C8EEC18-8D75-41B2-A177-8831D59D2D50}
Music (folder)                                  shell:::{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}
My Documents                                    shell:::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}
Network                                         shell:::{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}
Network and Sharing Center                      shell:::{8E908FC9-BECC-40f6-915B-F4CA0E70D03D}
Network Connections (in PC settings)            shell:::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}
Network Connections                             shell:::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}
                                                shell:::{992CFFA0-F557-101A-88EC-00DD010CCC48}
Network (WorkGroup)                             shell:::{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}
Notification Area Icons                         shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
NVIDIA Control Panel (if installed)             shell:::{0bbca823-e77d-419e-9a44-5adec2c8eeb0}
Offline Files Folder                            shell:::{AFDB1F70-2A4C-11d2-9039-00C04F8EEB3E}
OneDrive                                        shell:::{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}
Pen and Touch                                   shell:::{F82DF8F7-8B9F-442E-A48C-818EA735FF9B}
Personalization                                 shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921}
Pictures (folder)                               shell:::{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}
Portable Devices                                shell:::{35786D3C-B075-49b9-88DD-029876E11C01}
Power Options                                   shell:::{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}
Previous Versions Results Folder                shell:::{f8c2ab3b-17bc-41da-9758-339d7dbf2d88}
printhood delegate folder                       shell:::{ed50fc29-b964-48a9-afb3-15ebb9b97f36}
Printers                                        shell:::{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}
                                                shell:::{863aa9fd-42df-457b-8e4d-0de1b8015c60}
Programs and Features                           shell:::{7b81be6a-ce2b-4676-a29e-eb907a5126c5}
Public (folder)                                 shell:::{4336a54d-038b-4685-ab02-99bb52d3fb8b}
Quick access                                    shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}
Recent places                                   shell:::{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}
Recovery                                        shell:::{9FE63AFD-59CF-4419-9775-ABCC3849F861}
Recycle Bin                                     shell:::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Region and Language                             shell:::{62D8ED13-C9D0-4CE8-A914-47DD628FB1B0}
RemoteApp and Desktop Connections               shell:::{241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}
Remote Printers                                 shell:::{863aa9fd-42df-457b-8e4d-0de1b8015c60}
Removable Storage Devices                       shell:::{a6482830-08eb-41e2-84c1-73920c2badb9}
Results Folder                                  shell:::{2965e715-eb66-4719-b53f-1672673bbefa}
Run                                             shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
Search                                          shell:::{9343812e-1c37-4a49-a12e-4b2d810d956b}
Search Everywhere (modern)                      shell:::{2559a1f8-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
Search Files (modern)                           shell:::{2559a1f0-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
Security and Maintenance                        shell:::{BB64F8A7-BEE7-4E1A-AB8D-7D8273F7FDB6}
Set Program Access and Computer Defaults        shell:::{2559a1f7-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
Show Desktop                                    shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}
Sound                                           shell:::{F2DDFC82-8F12-4CDD-B7DC-D4FE1425AA4D}
Speech Recognition                              shell:::{58E3C745-D971-4081-9034-86E34B30836A}
Storage Spaces                                  shell:::{F942C606-0914-47AB-BE56-1321B8035096}
Sync Center                                     shell:::{9C73F5E5-7AE7-4E32-A8E8-8D23B85255BF}
Sync Setup Folder                               shell:::{2E9E59C0-B437-4981-A647-9C34B9B90891}
System                                          shell:::{BB06C0E4-D293-4f75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}
System Icons                                    shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
Tablet PC Settings                              shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}
Taskbar and Navigation properties               shell:::{0DF44EAA-FF21-4412-828E-260A8728E7F1}
Text to Speech                                  shell:::{D17D1D6D-CC3F-4815-8FE3-607E7D5D10B3}
This PC                                         shell:::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
Troubleshooting                                 shell:::{C58C4893-3BE0-4B45-ABB5-A63E4B8C8651}
User Accounts                                   shell:::{60632754-c523-4b62-b45c-4172da012619}
User Accounts (netplwiz)                        shell:::{7A9D77BD-5403-11d2-8785-2E0420524153}
User Pinned                                     shell:::{1f3427c8-5c10-4210-aa03-2ee45287d668}
%UserProfile%                                   shell:::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}
Videos (folder)                                 shell:::{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}
Web browser (default)                           shell:::{871C5380-42A0-1069-A2EA-08002B30309D}
Windows Defender                                shell:::{D8559EB9-20C0-410E-BEDA-7ED416AECC2A}
Windows Mobility Center                         shell:::{5ea4f148-308c-46d7-98a9-49041b1dd468}
Windows Features                                shell:::{67718415-c450-4f3c-bf8a-b487642dc39b}
Windows Firewall                                shell:::{4026492F-2F69-46B8-B9BF-5654FC07E423}
Windows To Go                                   shell:::{8E0C279D-0BD1-43C3-9EBD-31C3DC5B8A77}
Windows Update                                  shell:::{36eef7db-88ad-4e81-ad49-0e313f0c35f8}
Work Folders                                    shell:::{ECDB0924-4208-451E-8EE0-373C0956DE16}
```

For an updated list, look into your OS registry bellow the following key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions`

Answer (score 3):

The registry entry at 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow\Interval 
does set the interval in milliseconds as suggested by Psycogeek above but to activate you have to go to the setting window (by right clicking the desktop and selecting Personalize) which will appear to show the interval as 10 minutes but it hasn't actually been changed. Just close the setting window and the interval between pictures will change as immediately as specified. Alternatively you have to restart the computer. Change to 10000 decimal for a 10 second interval.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows key-R combo to get the RUN window - then type regdit - OK
Then you have to ALLOW this app to make changes . .  - say YES
Then go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow
At right hand side double click Interval and select Decimal display
Value data number is display time per slide in milliseconds - so 10000 will set a 10 second changeover time.

TWO POINTS:
a) if you set a default Interval less than 10 seconds (eg 5000 for 5 seconds) W10 seems to over-ride this and defaults to a 10 second minimum
b) if you have your screen extended to a second monitor or projector then the W10 default minimum change time seems to default to 20 seconds.

Does anyone know a way around these issues?

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).

Comment: @DavidPostill I think this does provide an answer (I haven't tested it) because it shows how you can change the interval to less than 2 minutes. The answer could use some better [formatting](http://superuser.com/help/formatting) though.

Comment: @cascer1 "Does anyone know a way around these issues?" is asking a new question.

Comment: @cascer1 OP has also indicated "Thank you, I've checked it, but it does not work." as the same suggestion was made as a comment on the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill Whoops, looks like I didn't check carefully. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

`control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper`
solve my problem and you do not need activation to windows 10
by using this

> shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper