# Windows slideshow of Images as a movie

Tags: video, images, slideshow

This is a simple problem that needs a lot of explanation. So bear with me.

I need help in finding a software or a hack to do the following:
I need to continuously display images in a folder as a slideshow. The images could be removed or put into the folder, but that shouldn't break the slideshow.

More clearly, at the front desk in our company, we've got a computer that displays posters of our upcoming events. I did this by dropping the images(posters) in windows movie maker and created a simple .mp4 movie. I play this movie fullscreen and set it on loop, and these images(posters) play all day.

The problem: We've got a lot of events happening, and creating a movie every single time by removing old event posters and adding new ones seems tedious. So, I was wondering if there is a software out there, that simply play the images in a folder as a slideshow. That way, all I need to do is to drop new images into the folder and remove old ones from there.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but if you choose the native *Slide show* option in Windows Explorer, does that update automatically as files are added/removed?

Comment: I don't have a second monitor with me right now to test this(since slideshow would take up the full screen and I need another screen to modify the files in the folder), will update as soon as I test, or if someone else gets to it before me. Thank you for the thought.

Comment: My second screen blanks out, you'd have to update the folder remotely over a network share.

Comment: When I tested, the Windows Photo Viewer slideshow did not update when a new file was placed in the folder. However, the Windows Desktop Background slideshow option does automatically update when new files are added to a folder. There are also purpose-built programs for this, as well as options such as configurations within Irfanview.

Comment: Windows Slideshow did not do it, as we would've to select the files that we need to play in the slideshow beforehand. This would work with removing old images, but wouldn't work with adding new images. The Windows Desktop Background slideshow did work. However, the only issue I had was the timer set for the slideshow. The minimum time we could do is 1 minute, while I need to do something like 10 seconds or less. A series of 30 images with 1-minute duration would mean that someone has to wait for 30 minutes to look again at the first image.

Comment: @davidmneedham Could you please tell me in a better detail about how to do it in Irfanview. Also, do you know off any purpose-built software that does this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/951677/windows-10-slide-show-shorter-than-1-minute
This seems to be a solution. I am still wondering if there's a specific software, but I guess this should do too.